# Tkinter opens console window with window

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am a complete newbie at Python. Meanwhile, I'm working with `Tkinter` to integrate a GUI into my application using Python 2.7. This is the code so far:

```
import Tkinter

top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.mainloop()
```

However, when I execute the file, a console window **and** the GUI pops up. How do I get rid of the console window during startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your Python script as `.pyw` (not `.pyc`). This will tell the invoker to to instantiate a console window. [Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=338601)

Note however, this will work for non-GUI based scripts too which can cause undesireqable behaviour - such as not being able to see your script.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. But, is there a python module/class method for this?

Comment: Not really. TKinter might be able to suppress it, but its unlikely as the invoker still has to open to run your script - `.pyw` prevents that. Alternatively, you can compile your application using `py2exe` or similar.